# How to stop a CCActionMoveBy function mid way?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a game where a sprite is moving using the CCActionMoveBy function, and it moves until its outside the screen and then comes back. However, if it hits another sprite before it reaches the end of the screen I want it to stop for half a sec before it returns back again, instead of keep going all the way to the end of the screen before returning. So how does one stop a CCActionMoveBy function mid way? and make it move somewhere else?

Thanks

Comment: assign a tag to the action and use `stopActionByTag` to stop the action.

Comment: Lovely, thanks Johnny Peter =)